# Segfault debian server

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault

we move our retail software to a new hardware (we passed from an ibm x3200 with sata 7200rpm disks to an ibm x3200 with sas 15000rpm disks) but after a few days with no problem at all we keep getting

> **Aug 29 08:39:50 server01 kernel: [64680.439253] retail-soft[1089]: segfault at 104 ip ? 081106ea sp bfd1b7c0 error 4 in retail-soft[8048000+18b000]**

in /var/log/messages and the software just hangs or gets closed.

We change the RAM assuming that was the problem but it keeps happening.

What else can we check?

Sorry about my english.

Thank You

**Updated**:
I checked free -m and it's showing 2015 as total when it has 8GB physically

Comment: Enable core dumps so you can get something to debug. Those pathetic kernel log messages about segfaults are no substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, it'll give you an idea: [Segmentation fault - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).  I'd try to move to another hardware it doesn't seem like it's RAM since you already changed it and that didn't help. Also make sure you're running latest stable version of software and latest updates for your OS as well.

Comment: We have installed the latest stable release of Debian. We also discarded a programming failure because the same software is running in other servers with no problems at all